# Powershell substituting parameters within a file

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a Ps script which is called from a `C#` application.

The Powershell script is being called with the format.

```
            var scriptFile = "./run_script.ps1 " +
                             $"-sql_server {'"' + serverName + '"'} " +
                             $"-database {'"' + dbName + '"'} ";

        MessageBox.Show(scriptFile);

            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"powershell.exe",
                Arguments = scriptFile,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            var process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
            process.Start();
```

The value of `servername` is being read from a configuration file. The message box comes up with the string below

```
./run_script.ps1 -sql_server "**Server1,5002**" -database "Test"
```

However from the script file

```
param ($sql_server,$database)
write-output "The deployment server is $sql_server"
```

The output from the C# application can be found below

The deployment server is *Server1 5002*

It's taking off, for the port number and replacing it with an empty space, thus causing the SQL connection to fail. What is surprising is that when the parameter is printed from the mo

I am lost as to what could be causing this, I have debugged the C# application and I can see that it's sending the string to the Ps file with a,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, the simplest solution is to use the `-File` [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) parameter explicitly:

```
Arguments = "-File " + scriptFile
```

`-File` ensures that, syntactic `"..."`-quoting aside, the arguments passed to the script file are interpreted as *literals*.

Without `-File`, `powershell.exe` defaults to `-Command` / `-c`, which causes the arguments to be interpreted as a *PowerShell command line*, which means that, after stripping syntactic `"..."` quoting around individual arguments, the arguments are space-concatenated and the resulting command line is then interpreted the same way it would be from inside PowerShell, causing the then-unquoted `**Server1,5002**` to be interpreted as an *array*.

Note that PowerShell [Core] v6+ ([`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh)) now defaults to `-File`.

---

Since, as you note in a comment, you *do* need `-Command` / `-c`, due to the need to pass an actual *array* as one of the arguments (which `-File` doesn't support), the solution is to either use `'...'` quoting in your arguments string or embed `\"...\"`-quoting *inside* your `"..."` strings:

```
var scriptFile = 
  $"./run_script.ps1 -sql_server '{serverName}' -database '{dbName}'";
```

Comment: That worked, another thing I did before was to add a tick as an escape. "server1`,5002"

Comment: Glado to hear it, @user5544; yes, individually `\``-escaping metacharacters works too.